# Generic installer builder for Linux

Tags: linux, installer

**Problem:**

How can I create a binary installer for different Linux distros? I want this for an open source software. Maybe generate `.sh` file?

**Required Software:** Generic installer builder for Linux. Installer can be based on `bash/sh`. GUI is optional.

**Price**: Open Source, Free, or free for open source.

**Real world samples**: Installer for VirtualBox guest add-ons, PyCharm installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things which seem to fit the bill, [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/) and [Flatpak](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/first-build.html). The aim of both is to package up all dependencies to work across distributions and versions. Of the two Flatpak is more 'universal', whilst Snap is used quite heavily by Ubuntu.

Comment: Don't forget [AppImage](https://appimage.org/)! I'd probably never use Snap, and I don't like Flatpack that much. To use an AppImage on any distro, the user doesn't need to install any "handling package" like one must with Snap and Flatpak. Simply drop the AppImage in dome directory, make it executable and run it. Done.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatives:**

Makeself: https://github.com/megastep/makeself

> makeself.sh is a small shell script that generates a self-extractable
>   compressed tar archive from a directory. The resulting file appears as
>   a shell script (many of those have a .run suffix), and can be launched
>   as is. The archive will then uncompress itself to a temporary
>   directory and an optional arbitrary command will be executed (for
>   example an installation script). This is pretty similar to archives
>   generated with WinZip Self-Extractor in the Windows world. Makeself
>   archives also include checksums for integrity self-validation (CRC
>   and/or MD5/SHA256 checksums).